# nodejs firebase query now work , how i can edit it

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to update field in database (firabase) by cloud function   =>  nodejs

[image]

in this doc
i dont know name of doc i mean doc id

[image]

i wanna to update timeSlotId
i know timeSlotId value and userId value

Together these values ​​are not repeatable

so this is my query

```
     await db.collection("Order")
     .where("timeSlotId", "==", timeSlotNow.id)
     .where("userId" , "==" , request.userId)
     .update({timeSlotId : timeSlotChanged.id });
```

but now work

Comment: You mention "by cloud function => nodejs", so why do you tag the question with the `flutter` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`db.collection("Order").where("timeSlotId", "==", timeSlotNow.id).where("userId" , "==" , request.userId)` defines a `Query` which does not have an `update()` method.

You need to execute the query with the `get()` method in order to get the corresponding document(s) and then update the document(s) returned by the query.

The following code should do the trick. **I make the assumption the query returns only one document: if this assumption is not correct, see below.**

```
const querySnapshot = await db.collection("Order")
     .where("timeSlotId", "==", timeSlotNow.id)
     .where("userId" , "==" , request.userId)
     .get(); // <=== See the get() method call

querySnapshot.docs[0].ref.update({timeSlotId : timeSlotChanged.id });
```

---

If the query returns several documents and you want to update all of them, you can do as follows:

```
const querySnapshot = await db.collection("Order")
     .where("timeSlotId", "==", timeSlotNow.id)
     .where("userId" , "==" , request.userId)
     .get(); // <=== See the get() method call

const batch = db.batch();

querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    batch.update(doc.ref, {timeSlotId : timeSlotChanged.id });
});

await batch.commit();
```